# JPA/Hibernate write only field with no read

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following class :

```
    public class Section {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

 ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID")
    private Section section;  // need this write only

    @OneToMany
    private List<Section> sectionList;

}
```

I want to retrieve the section list when reading the section, but I don't want to get the section. is that possible ? I can't use @Transient because I need the section to be persisted.

Note: I will use findAll from spring repository so I will not use native query.

Comment: nice question, but doesn't this depend on your query?

Comment: @YCF_L I will use spring jpa repository , so I will not use native query. findAll for example

Comment: You can go with the lazy loading. Don't try to call the getter method. And when you need to save just pass it to setter

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you try with removing the `getSection` from your entity, I'm not fully sure, but try it

Comment: I think @DKAnsh has nice idea this will work , it has one limitation if I'm using spring-jpa open in view it will be serialized because it will call the getter automatically

Comment: @YCF_L I will try your solution to remove the getter , because lazy loading won't work with open-in view , the field will be serialized and getter will be called automatically

Comment: You can use both together (lazy loading as well as removing the getter method). By using lazy loading, it will not load the data unnecessary as you are not going to get that data.

Comment: @DKAnsh Thanks, let me try to remove the getter and see if it works.

Comment: Just removing the getter won't do any good. Fact that you can't get it is not same as it's not loaded in the object. You should mark section list as lazy

Comment: @AdityaNarayanDixit so I need to use both ? no getter and lazy loading ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the sectionList fetch type as lazy and remove its getter from the class Section.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SECTION_ID")
private Section section;
```

Comment: He wants to make the section as write-only, not the List<section>.

Comment: it worked to set the data in DB, I wondered how hibernate read the section ? does it use reflection instead of getter ?

Comment: found the answer, as I'm using the @Id on field so it's field based access no need for getters and setters that's why the persist work.